# Pinescript short only strategy showing "no data"

Tags: pine-script

trying to create a short only strategy but getting "no data" error.

```
enterIndex = 0.0
enterIndex := enterIndex[1]
inPosition  = not na(strategy.position_size) and strategy.position_size<0
if inPosition and na(enterIndex)
    enterIndex := bar_index

if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("SHORT", strategy.short)
    
if (not na(enterIndex) and bar_index - enterIndex + 1 >= 3 )  

    strategy.close( "CLOSE")
```

Answer (score 0):

You must close the position that you opened.

The IDs must match.
In your case, if you opened a position  SHORT , you must also close it.

if (shortCondition)
strategy.entry("SHORT", strategy.short)

if (not na(enterIndex) and bar_index - enterIndex + 1 >= 3 )

```
strategy.close( "SHORT")
```